# Rotate a sphere about an arbitrary axis using 3 angles relative to coordinate axes?

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, rotations, spherical-trigonometry

I have a globe in 3D Euclidean space with the center of the globe at the origin, only the globe is tilted off axis by $\phi$ degrees so it doesn't rotate around the z-axis anymore, but an arbitrary one determined by $\phi$.

Is it possible to do the equivalent of spinning the globe around its tilted axis by $\theta$ degrees using rotations relative to the 3 coordinate axes? How would I relate $\phi$ and $\theta$ with rotations $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ around the x, y, and z-coordinate axes, respectively?

##### Edit

I've tried figuring this out with some spherical trig. Here's a little diagram I made:

[image]

In this scenario I want to revolve a body like the sun along a path ("Sun arc") around an arbitrary axis ("Sun axis"). It looks to me like angles $A$ and $B$ are always $\frac{\pi}{2}$, $C$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}-\phi$, angle $a$ and $b$ are my $\theta$, and that just leaves to solve for angle $c$, which I think ends up just being $c=\sin^{-1}(\sin\theta\sin\phi)$ by spherical law of sines. So basically my rotations around the coordinate axes *should* be $x=0, y=\theta, z=\sin^{-1}(\sin\theta\sin\phi)$. This doesn't seem quite right however, when I use it for my sun animation. The rotation is close, but just not quite right for some reason, so I must have something off here.

If anyone is curious about what I'm actually doing, here is an animation of the sun and stars I'm making:

[image]

The sun and stars should be rotating around the same axis so they move together, however you can see from the animation this isn't quite the case. For the sun movement, I am able to specify azimuth and elevation angles, and I'm considering its path the source of truth (its easier for me to understand its rotation axis). For the star background, I have to rotate a large sphere with the stars printed on it, and I can only specify rotations around the coordinate axes for this. The key difficulty is that when I rotate around the x-axis for example, it does not change the coordinate system. Rotating around z *after* rotating around x still just rotates around the original z axis. Getting these to behave the same using different coordinate systems is proving very tricky!

##### Edit 2

I think I found a better way to frame this. So the usual way to do this would be to rotate the space up (around the x or y axis) and then rotate the space around the z axis. Using the usual rotation matrices, this would be $R_z(\gamma)R_x(\alpha)p$, where $p$ is a point in the space. I've realized what I'm actually trying to do is reverse the order of those transformations but achieve the same resulting $p$, so that I first rotate the space around x or y, and *then* around z. So I want $R_x(\alpha)R_z(\gamma)p$. The problem of course, is that to rotate around an arbitrary axis, $\gamma$ must now change with $\alpha$, where it could have stayed constant before. I need a way to compute the correct $\gamma$ from $\alpha$.

Comment: Tilt the globe's axis back to the $z$-axis. Rotate by $\theta$ and undo the tilt. (3 steps).

Comment: I literally need the rotation values for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ though. In this case those are the only inputs I have to actually turn the globe.

Comment: [This](http://eecs.qmul.ac.uk/~gslabaugh/publications/euler.pdf) shows how to solve for the three angles, given a rotation matrix.

Comment: @KurtG. how would I get a rotation matrix, given an axis tilt and rotation around that axis? There needs to be some sort of space conversion I think?

Comment: The rotation matrix you start with is a product of the three matrices I described in the first comment. There is a lot of work to do. If you'd use quaternions instead the rotation around the tilted axis comes almost for free.

Comment: Yeah I understand how I would use rotation matrices if I was able to. I cannot use them in this circumstance. I am not rotating points the way this would normally be done. I _have_ to directly relate an azimuth and elevation angle ($\phi$ and $\theta$) to angles about the coordinate axes. If matrices can be involved, great, but I would have to relate the usual rotation matrices with $\phi$ and $\theta$, which is the non-intuitive part for me.

Comment: You insist -for whatever reason- on deriving the angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ around the $x,y,z$ axes for a given rotation (around a tilted $z$ axis). Why can matrices not be used? I don't get it .  A constraint of the program you are using ?

Comment: Yes a constraint of the animation program. I've added some detail to the original question that might help clarify

Comment: In that case I would write a bit of python code to do all those calculations to get the angles. Please understand that this is a math site, not a hotline for particular animation  programs. If the program doesn't allow you to do what you want you should find ways around it. Have shown two .

Comment: Ok thanks for the help...

Comment: I don't understand why you would decompose the rotation of the globe about its tilted axis into the multiplication of three separate rotations about the coordinate axes.  That seems to be unnecessary at all.  Please check my solution which I will post shortly.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the problem. There should be no multiplication of rotation matrices here, no matrices involved at all in fact, as I've stated. This is a different problem. There are no points to multiply against, I can only specify rotation angles. The answer I am looking for will relate angles to angles. If rotation matrices factor into the derivation, fine, but they won't be involved in the final function I would like to make.

Answer (score 1):

The axis of rotation is specified with respect to the stationary coordinate axes using two angles $\theta_A$ and $\phi_A$, which are the angular spherical coordinates of the unit vector along the axis.  In particular, the axis is given by

$ n = (\sin \theta_A \cos \phi_A , \sin \theta_A \sin \phi_A, \cos \theta_A)$

Along with vector $n$ we need two other unit vectors, so that the set of these three vectors make up an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$.  These two vectors can be conveniently chosen to be

$u_1 = (\cos \theta_A \cos \phi_A , \cos \theta_A \sin \phi_A, -\sin \theta_A) $

$ u_2 = ( - \sin \phi_A , \cos \phi_A , 0 ) $

Now the orthonormal set is the rotation matrix $R_1$ whose columns are $u_1, u_2 , n$, i.e.

$R_1 = [u_1, u_2, n ]$

A point $P \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ has an equivalent coordinate vector $Q$ in the $R_1$ coordinate system given by

$ P = R_1 Q $

In other words,

$Q = R_1^T P $

Now to rotate $P$ about the axis $n$ is to rotate $Q$ about the $z$-axis of the $R_1$ system.  So if we rotate by an angle of $\theta$, then the image of $Q$ in the $R_1$ coordinate system will be

$Q' = R_z Q $

where $R_z = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta && - \sin \theta && 0 \\ \sin \theta && \cos \theta && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

And now we can obtain the image of $P$ as being

$P' = R_1 Q' = R_1 R_z Q = R_1 R_z R_1^T P $

This is all you need to rotate a point about a tilted axis.